# Skype for Business Channel: Identify Device Type Mobile or Desktop

Tags: azure, botframework, skype-for-business

We have Azure Bot Service implemented with Skye for Business as Channel. As part of response display, we have requirement to format the text like bold and display data in tables.

The formatting is working fine in when users are using bot in Desktop version of Skype for Business.  In mobile version of Skype for Business, the format is not displaying properly instead displaying HTML tags used to format the text.

Is there any way we can identify device type using by the user i.e. mobile or desktop version? So that we can have conditional format of the text and display only plain text responses if users are chatting using mobile version of Skype for business.

Thank you in advance.